# How to clone homepage for multi region site?

Tags: multisite, multisite-user-management, clone-site

How would i clone the homepage of my website ? I understand and have used to plugins that duplicate your page, the difficulty I am having is that I need to create a multi-site from 1 domain.

For example, I have

mywebsite.com - this targets my usa audience

mywebsite.com/es - this would target spanish audience

I would really like to know how I would duplicate mywebsite.com and then edit that page and content so that it is in spanis

If you know, please can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Multisites don't have to be separate domains, they can be subfolders. You can have your root/original blog/site at `/` then put new sites at `/es/` `/fr/` etc etc.

As for how you would copy your content to that site however, WordPress provides no solution here other than a manual copy/paste. You would need to reconstruct all the pages and copy what content you have in the main site to these secondary sites. You would need to translate all this content by hand anyway.

For any automation you would need to use 3rd party plugins. Some multilingual plugins rely on multisites and would do all of this automatically.